# JTDS not connecting to correct database

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am using JTDS to connect to a MS SQL Server. Connection to the database is no problem, but when I try to execute a statement, I get a Database 'java' does not exist exception.

ConnectionString:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;DatabaseName=MyDatabase;user=testuser;password=testpassword");
```

Trying to execute the script:

```
private void runStatement(String scriptLocation) {
    if(scriptLocation == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(scriptLocation);
        String query = is.toString();
        is.close();

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch(IOException | SQLException ex) {
        log.warning(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
WARNING: Database 'java' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'java' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1427)
    at com.exampe.MyJTDSConnection.runStatement(MyJTDSConnection.java:238)
    at com.exampe.MyJTDSConnection.loadPageTitle(MyJTDSConnection.java:208)
    at com.exampe.MyJTDSConnection.runTesting(MyJTDSConnection.java:69)
    at com.exampe.SeleniumTesting.runTest(SeleniumTesting.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

Comment: is.toString() does not give you what you think it does. You must *read* the input stream to get your "script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment to your question, applying the `.toString()` method to the InputStream object does not read the InputStream. Instead it just returns a String representation of the object itself, not what the object contains.

For example, my Java project has a resource file named "script.sql" that contains:

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION
```

The following code compares the result of simply doing a `.toString()` on the object vs. using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to actually *read* the InputStream into a String:

```java
package resourceTest;

import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class ResourceTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream is = ResourceTestMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/script.sql")) {
            String toStringValue = is.toString();
            String contents = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
            is.close();
            System.out.println("is.toString() returned:");
            System.out.println("    " + toStringValue);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("IOUtils.toString(is, \"UTF-8\") returned:");
            System.out.println("    " + contents);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

}
```

The results are:

```
is.toString() returned:
    java.io.BufferedInputStream@804a77

IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8") returned:
    SELECT @@VERSION
```